# e.preventDefault() not working, return false and more tried

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to submit data via ajax and input to the database. But the only way I can get it work is if it redirects to the PHP file. I have tried using `e.preventDefault();`, `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` and `return false;` but nothing works. I eventually did this where it runs the function when the form submits, it gets the answer back from the PHP file, but does not input into the database.

This is my code that works (but loads the PHP page):

```
function uploadImage(e) {
e.preventDefault();
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
var input = document.getElementById("images"),
    date = document.getElementById("image_date").value,
    formdata = new FormData();

$.ajax({
    url: "submit_image.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: formdata,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (res) {
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = res;
        hideImageUpload(); 
        removeAllPosts();
        getAllPosts();
    }
});

return false;
}
```

And here is the code that does not work, but gets a response:

```
$('#image_upload_form').on('submit', function uploadImage(e) {

    var input = document.getElementById("images"),
    date = document.getElementById("image_date").value,
    formdata = new FormData();

    $.ajax({
        url: "submit_image.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: formdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (res) {
            document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = res;
            hideImageUpload(); 
            removeAllPosts();
            getAllPosts();
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;

});
```

and here is the PHP:

```
<?php
    require_once 'core/init.php';
    $user = new User();
    $errors = $_FILES["images"]["error"];
    $date = $_POST['image_date'];
    $d = explode("/", $date);
    $nd = $d[2] . '-' . $d[0] . '-' . $d[1] . ' 00:00:00';
    echo $nd;
    foreach ($errors as $key => $error) {
        if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $name = $_FILES["images"]["name"][$key];
            //$ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $name = explode("_", $name);
            $imagename='';
            foreach($name as $letter){
                $imagename .= $letter;
            }

            move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$key], "images/uploads/" . $user->data()->id . '_' . $imagename);

            $user->create('photos', array(
                'osid' => $user->data()->id,
                'user' => $user->data()->username,
                'gallery' => 'Uploads',
                'filename' => "images/uploads/" . $user->data()->id . '_' . $imagename,
                'uploaddate' => $nd
            ));
            $user->create('status', array(
                'osid' => $user->data()->id,
                'account_name' => $user->data()->username,
                'author' => $user->data()->name . ' ' . $user->data()->surname,
                'type' => 'image',
                'data' => "images/uploads/" . $user->data()->id . '_' . $imagename,
                'postdate' => $nd
            ));
        }
    }  


    echo "<h2>Successfully Uploaded Images</h2>";
```

is there something that I am missing??

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the validity of your php, but in your AJAX call you are not appending the elements to the formdata object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects

```
$('#image_upload_form').on('submit', function uploadImage(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('images', $('#images')[0].files[0]);
    formdata.append('image_date', $('#image_date').val());

    $.ajax({
        url: "submit_image.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: formdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (res) {
            $("#response").html(res);
            //or console.log(res); and see the response in the console window (press F12)
            hideImageUpload(); 
            removeAllPosts();
            getAllPosts();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

You can use the jQuery methods rather than JavaScript document.getElementById to get your elements (and data), makes the code easier to read.

Comment: This is still opening the PHP file unfortunately

Comment: I added `return false;` and it worked, but when appending, it says "not enough arguments, so I added arguments: `formdata.append("images", $('#images'));` and now it is making that value `#`?

Comment: @user3185528 I updated the code sample, try that. Also, I had a typo, it should have been `$("#response").html(res)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `submit()` method that triggers the submit event, or attaches a function to run when a submit event occurs.

You can cancel the submit action by calling `.preventDefault()` on the event object or by returning `false` from your handler. Check jQuery [.submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) doc.

You can build your FormData object by calling `append()` method, like this:

`formdata.append('images', $('#images').files[0]);`

Check [FormData Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects) doc

```
$("#image_upload_form").submit(function( event ) {

    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('images', $('#images').files[0]);
    formdata.append('image_date', $('#image_date').val());

    $.ajax({
        url: "submit_image.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: formdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (res) {
            document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = res;
            hideImageUpload(); 
            removeAllPosts();
            getAllPosts();
        }
    });


    event.preventDefault();

});
```

For more `ajax()` method info I recommend read this [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)